# From database via join to REST how does it work?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mariadb

I have a database with two tables (orders & orderProducts) with 1:n-Relation.
I would like to combine this two tables to give a JSON to my REST-Tool.

For this I have the following SQL-Query:

```
 $sqlQueryAll = "SELECT
                    t1.id,
                    t1.name,

                    t2.pId,
                    t2.anzahl,
                    t2.name as pName,
                    t2.preis,

                    FROM orders as t1
                  JOIN orderProducts as t2 ON t1.id = t2.orderId
                  WHERE t1.id <= ?";
```

Here I will get this Array back:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
            [id] => 1000
            [name] => Nurten
            [pId] => 26
            [anzahl] => 1
            [pName] => Fitness-Teller
            [preis] => 12.90
        )
    [1] => Array(
            [id] => 1001
            [name] => Kutscha
            [pId] => 94
            [anzahl] => 1
            [pName] => Pizza Parma
            [preis] => 12.90
        )
    [2] => Array(
            [id] => 1001
            [name] => Kutscha
            [pId] => 75
            [anzahl] => 1
            [pName] => Pizza Margherita
            [preis] => 6.50
        )
)
```

I would like to have the following JSON:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1000
        [name] => Nurten
        [products] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                        [pId] => 26
                        [anzahl] => 1
                        [pName] => Fitness-Teller
                        [preis] => 12.90
                    )
           )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 1001
        [name] => Kutscha
        [products] => Array(
                [0] => Array(
                        [pId] => 94
                        [anzahl] => 1
                        [pName] => Pizza Parma
                        [preis] => 12.90
                    )
                [1] => Array(
                        [pId] => 75
                        [anzahl] => 1
                        [pName] => Pizza Margherita
                        [preis] => 6.50
                    )
            )

    )
)
```

For this I'am using the following working PHP code:

```
$artikelFields = ['pId', 'anzahl', 'pName', 'preis'];
$id_="";  #new Product Kenner
$orders = [];
$i = -1;
foreach ($result2 as $row)  {

    if ($row['id'] != $id_) {

          # reset
          $i++;
          unset($order);
          $id_ = $row['id'];

          # write Array from Fields without $artikelFields
          foreach ($row as $field =>$value)  {
            if (!in_array($field, $artikelFields)) {
              $order[$field] = $value;
            }
          }

          # write Artikel to array[products]
          $newArtikel = array();
          foreach ($artikelFields as $a)  {
              $newArtikel[$a] = $row[$a];
          }
          $order['products'][] = $newArtikel;

    } else {

          # write only array[products]
          $newArtikel = array();
          foreach ($artikelFields as $a)  {
              $newArtikel[$a] = $row[$a];
          }
          $order['products'][] = $newArtikel;

    }

    $orders[$i] = $order;


} /* !foreach */
```

I'am a bit unsecure why this seems to be very complicated. Isn't there any more convienience way to achive this? (With an other query maybe).

Comment: The query can't produce nested arrays, so you have to restructure the result yourself one way or another. With that being said, working solutions where you are looking for improvements would be a better fit over at [Code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why do consider this code complicated? Is there any performance issue or do you have situations when the code produces incorrect output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to group data is to use a "shared" key (here, the user id), initialize the row the first time you meet the user id, then, add the products to the 'product' key.

```
$out = [];
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    if (!isset($out[$result['id']])) {
       $out[$result['id']] = [
          'id'   => $result['id'],
          'name' => $result['name'],
       ];
    }

    $out[$result['id']]['products'][] = [
          'pId'    => $result['pId'],
          'anzahl' => $result['anzahl'],
          'pName'  => $result['pName'],
          'preis'  => $result['preis'],
    ];
}
var_export(array_values($out));
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/q0jN4)

You can also use `array_filter` :

```
$out = [];
foreach ($results as $result)
{
    if (!isset($out[$result['id']])) {
       $out[$result['id']] = array_filter($result, function($key) { 
        return in_array($key, ['id','name']); 
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    }

    $out[$result['id']]['products'][] = array_filter($result, function($key) { 
        return in_array($key, ['pId','anzahl','pName','preis']); 
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
}
print_r(array_values($out));
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/DTCXH)

Comment: Where are you setting the id? Gets error:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: I've used `$result->id` instead of `$result['id']` (updated answer).

Comment: gets still error:  Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Comment: Can you check this demo https://3v4l.org/q0jN4 ? (missed another '->').

Comment: Your demo is working. I have some different result on PHP 7.3.26-nmm1
The id is another: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1000 shout be 0 not 1000

Comment: I think the compiler of the demo do not work correct. The output you coded is $result['id] witch is 1000/1001. Do you have any idea to correct it?

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. The `$result['id']` refers to the initial array as given in your question. `$result['id']` is an integer. As you can see in [this](https://3v4l.org/n9nnu), keys in the output are ID (I removed `array_values()`).

Comment: OK I get it. array_values() does the trick. Thanks